# Obscurify react code in production by automatically changing all the function and variable names

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, webpack

Are there any libs that help obscurify a react build for production?

Something like:

```
const MyComp = () = > {
 const {propa, propb} = useMyfunc()
 return(...)
}
```

to

```
const xyz = () = > {
 const {yxz, zyx} = zzz()
 return(...)
}
```

Comment: Hello @docHoliday, maybe check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123885/when-does-create-react-app-obfuscate-or-minify-code

Comment: I saw it, but it doesn't answer my question. I guess there isn't such a lib and I wonder why

Comment: production code is usually already minified which is a nightmare to read anyhow

Comment: CRA default deployment will obfuscate the code

Comment: Maybe use webpack to do this. Can you check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59162268/8660527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right choice would be [Terser](https://github.com/terser/terser). it is availble along with webpack too ([terser-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser-webpack-plugin)) for `ES6+`.

`uglify-es` is [no longer maintained](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/3156#issuecomment-392943058) and `uglify-js` does not support ES6+.

You can refer to benchmarks for different packages from this [article](https://github.com/babel/minify#benchmarks).

Answer (score 2):

Is [this library](https://blog.jscrambler.com/protecting-your-react-js-source-code-with-jscrambler/) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever try [this](https://obfuscator.io/) package?
this is a very professional package for obfuscate js codes which convert your code:

```
const MyComp = () = > {
  const {propa, propb} = useMyfunc()
  return(...)
}
```

to this:

```
const MyComp=()=>{const {propa:_0xa95d6e,propb:_0xfaabf6}=useMyfunc();return _0xa95d6e+_0xfaabf6;};
```

Answer (score 2):

*Complementing [Ashwin R's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68177618/19005300) response...*

As pointed out, [Terser](https://terser.org/) is a good choice for doing it.

React uses some form of [UglifyJS](https://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/) to minify your code on build, but in order to obfuscate variables and function names I did the following:

**Instructions:**

1° - Install Terser

`npm install terser`

2° - Modify package.json:

```
    "terser": "terser ./build/static/js/*.js -c -m --mangle-props regex=/_$/",
    "build": "react-scripts build && npm run terser"
```

That seems to have worked for me; hopefully it does for you as well!

Answer (score 1):

[UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS#readme) has options to mangle (obscurify) names:

**Sample input:**

```
const MyComp = function() {
const {propa, propb} = useMyfunc()
    return(1)
}
```

**Sample output:**

```
const n=function(){const{propa:n,propb:o}=useMyfunc();return 1};
```

Try it yourself: https://www.uglifyjs.net/

`useMyfunc` cannot be mangled unless the function definition is included (otherwise the function call would fail.) Similarly, mangling top-level globals like `MyComp` may break anything that uses that component.

If you bundle all your React code into a single file before mangling, it should work because all the references will be mangled to correctly matching names.

React already uses a minifier like UglifyJS, so you may be able to just modify some configuration files. Note [source maps will undermine any mangling, so they should be disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49123885/117030). (I think React is more interested in the smaller JS files than obscuring code.)

Answer (score 0):

**react-obfuscate**

There is one npm repository that takes care of react code obfuscation. Below is the link for the same -
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-obfuscate

Basic steps are written in the repo documentation itself.

**Jscrambler**

Another tool that I find interesting is Jscrambler.

https://blog.jscrambler.com/protecting-your-react-js-source-code-with-jscrambler/