# How to sell a chrome extension without leaking the source code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, crx

I developed an chrome extension I want to sell to a client, I want to charge my clients a little more if they also want to have the source code.
Seems like the .zip file or .crx file I send him is not a safe way to do so, he can easily unzip it and has access to the whole source code.

I don't want to publish it to the Google Chrome Store because that mostly takes weeks to get reviewed and published.

Any solution to this?

Comment: There's no way. You can use an obfuscator to mangle the code, but it can be still reversed. Note that a published extension's code is just as easy to inspect and debug in the built-in devtools or a file manager as a standalone crx/zip.

Comment: Maybe if your extension uses lots of WebAssembly code? But I've never done that, so I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: What you can have is an obfuscated version and a non-obfuscated one with well structured code and comments. My advice would be to not use that as a marketing strategy, instead what you could do is provide a product key that allows your customers to use customization files, or more advanced features of your software.

Comment: I'm not sure about normal JS, but webpack can bundle all of your TS into one really difficult to reverse JS file. [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091831/how-can-i-obfuscate-js-files-using-webpack).

Answer (score 0):

Publishing on the store should not take weeks. It normally takes a few days, though.

Anything published to the Chrome Web Store can be downloaded, and the same source you would submit to the store would be available to them. They have to be available, its an interpreted language.

[We haven't allowed obfuscated extensions for nearly half a decade](https://blog.chromium.org/2018/10/trustworthy-chrome-extensions-by-default.html).

I encourage you to look at the source code for any of the top extensions from the store. [Here is Grammarly](https://robwu.nl/crxviewer/?crx=https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grammarly-grammar-checker/kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen), for example. It is almost always more difficult to reverse engineer a modern web property than it is to remake it from scratch.

In short - you don't need to worry about "leaking the source".